# Intercepting mobile game packets with mitmproxy

Tags: ios, mitmproxy

I am using `mitmproxy` to intercept a iOS mobile games packets to understand the network structure. I can see the http connections to login to the game, but once that happens, I cannot see the packets  when I interact inside the game.

[image: windows console]

There should be flows after this that show when I do stuff in the game (looking at chat, completing levels, etc).

Comment: Games where multiple users interact in a virtual environment (e.g. MMORPG) usually use UDP traffic for communication instead of HTTP traffic. As you can only configure an HTTP proxy in iOS raw TCP and UDP connections are not affected and thus bypass your mitmproxy instance -> you can not see them. Use a separate Wifi network and capture all data using Wireshark/tshark in the Wifi router or the upstream network connection.

Comment: @Robert Thank you very much. I have seen some people mention you can connect the iOS device to a mac and use wireshark, but I'm using windows. Could you explain what you mean by "In the wifi router"? I'm not sure mine can do that, but I can sure try

Comment: For analyzing device traffic I recommend to use a separate Wifi router which supports sniffing and where only the device to be analyzed is connected to it's Wifi. I usually use a Raspberry Pi with OpenWRT installed. https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/misc/tcpdump_wireshark With Windows Internet sharing is too complicated.

Comment: Alternatively, take a look at mitmproxy's WireGuard mode: https://mitmproxy.org/posts/wireguard-mode/